# Threads & Semaphores Solution

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I have a problem that i need to solve, here is the explanation of the problem:

- I have n students threads
- I have single teacher thread
- Teach can assist only one student at time
- Students are suppose to call teacher for help, so when the first student comes to TA, other    students who comes and found TA is busy will have to wait on chairs, there are only 3 chairs
- Other students that come and found the chairs full, will have to comeback later
- If the teacher have no students being assisted he will check for students on the chairs, if there are none he will go to sleep (do nothing)

This problem have to implemented using Threads and Semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

1) I would have one teacher thread and N student threads (like you have).

2) I would have *one* semaphore.

3) I would have a *chairs array* (your "queue"); each element initialized to -1.

4) Each time a teacher can see a student, he locks the array, picks one student, "clears" the chair, and unlocks the array.

5) Each time a student wants to wait, he checks if there's a free chair, locks the array, "sets" the chair, and unlocks the array.

6) I would "malloc()", then initialize, the chairs array as soon as you know how many students you'll have.

7) If this were C++, "teacher", "student" and "chairs" would each be classes.

IMHO...

Comment: Will that is what i am doing, but instead of going in the hassle of implementing an array, i used a semaphore with 4 values which decrements and increments with every student in and out

Comment: I am trying your solution now, but can you tell me how to handle the first student that comes in, i mean the one that is not added in the queue